# Script ideas for configuring VPN connection

Tags: bash, scripts, network-manager, vpn

After some bad crashes of my system, I decided to take a more organized approach and develop a bash script that will handle most of the things I tend to configure manually after a fresh installation (from theme installation to setting corporate proxy variables, etc). I'm using 22.04.

My company uses the Cisco openconnect VPN protocol and its configuration is shown below:

[image]

What I want to achieve, is to create and save this connection with a bash script so that it becomes available in my Network Manager interface once I run my post-installation script. Would that be possible programmatically?